# How to set default value from google chart filter

Tags: google-visualization

I would like to load category chart filter with current month name which already exists in the drop down. here is the code. I tried with updating selectedValues, but no luck.

```
 var filterFrequencyData = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper(
            {
                'controlType': 'CategoryFilter',
                'containerId': 'filterFrequencyDataHtml',
                'options':
                    {
                        'filterColumnIndex': '5',
                        'ui':
                            {
                                'label': '',
                                'labelSeparator': ':',
                                'labelStacking': 'vertical',
                                'allowTyping': false,
                                'allowNone': true,
                                'allowMultiple': false
                            }
                        //'state': { 'selectedValues': [new Date().getMonth()] }
                    }
            });
```

Comment: `new Date().getMonth()` returns a number -- is the full month name displayed in the list? or abbr?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the state property.

```
var initState = { selectedValues: [] };
// replace the 2 below with the index required
initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(2));

var columnFilter = new window.google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
            controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
            containerId: 'columnfilter',
            dataTable: columns,
            state: initState,
            options: {
                filterColumnLabel: 'value',
                ui: {
                    label: 'Columns',
                    allowTyping: false,
                    allowMultiple: true,
                    allowNone: true,
                    selectedValuesLayout: 'belowWrapped'
                }
            }
        });
```